# getting summary of names in two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames of more than 200 columns and i want to create a summary to check if the names of columns are matching. i want o create a function for that.

i want to compare matching names of two data frame if they matching exactly then join them other with  bind that in new row.

```
df <- data.frame(EXT=c(1),MAN=c(2),MANi=c(2),nune=c(2),klay=c(4),emial=c("dd"),Pass=c(99),fri=c("TGA"),
                 mkl=c("nhi"),kin=c(7),munc=c(6),lone=c(44),wond=c("tko"))

df1 <- data.frame(EXT=c(1),MAN=c(2),MANi=c(2),nune=c(2),klay=c(4),emial=c("dd"),PASS=c(99),fri=c("TGA"),
                 mkl=c("nhi"),kin=c(7),MUNC=c(6),lone=c(44),hulu=c("kra"),kone=("hab"))
```

the required output should be like

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? Are the dataframes guaranteed to have the same number of rows?

Comment: i have tried bindrows and merge but didn't work. number of rows can varies for both of data frames

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried? If the number of rows can vary then how do you figure out which rows to compare?

Comment: actually there is no requirements of rows , names1 are the column names of df and names2 is the column names of df1. so want to pull names of df and fd1 and then compare column names like the summary as showed as required output

Comment: oh, I thought the names were in the columns, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compare_names <- function(df1, df2) {
  # Get All Names to start with.
  out <- data.frame(names1 = unique(c(names(df1), names(df2))))

  # Copy them over.
  out$names2 <- out$names1

  # Set them to NA if they are not present.
  out$names1[!(out$names1 %in% names(df1))] <- NA
  out$names2[!(out$names2 %in% names(df2))] <- NA

  # If they are not NA in both columns above then they are matching.
  out$matching <- !is.na(out$names1) & !is.na(out$names2)
  out
}
```